# C# - set empty delegate for event

Tags: c#-4.0, event-handling

```
public event EventHandler MyButtonClick = delegate { };
```

The construction above allows to not check if there is any subscriber:

```
public virtual void OnMyButtonClick(EventHandler e)
        {
            this.MyButtonClick(this, e);
        }
```

in stead of

```
  public virtual void OnMyButtonClick(EventHandler e)
            { 
                if (MyButtonClick!=null)
                   this.MyButtonClick(this, e);
            }
```

But is it really a good idea? Is this the only benefit: to not check if any subscriber exists?

UPDATE: Here is example

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public event EventHandler MyButtonClick;
            //= delegate { };

        public void OnButtonClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            MyButtonClick(this, e);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testClass = new TestClass();
            //it throws an exception
            testClass.OnButtonClick(new EventArgs());

            // if you add an handler it will call it

            testClass.MyButtonClick += myCustomHandler;
            testClass.OnButtonClick(new EventArgs()); // myCustomHandler has been invoiked

        }

        private static void myCustomHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("myCustomHandler has been invoiked");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it even let you do that? What if someone sets `MyButtonClick = null;`?

Comment: That shouldn't work, you can't reassign to an event name.

Comment: @LKIM, what do you mean? `new TestClass().MyButtonClick = null;`? It doesn't compile.

Comment: Try this:
`class Test
{
  public event EventHandler MyEvent = delegate { };

  public void FireEvent()
  {
    MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }

  public void ClearEvent()
  {
    MyEvent = null;
  }
}

static class Program
{
  [STAThread]
  static void Main()
  {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.FireEvent();
    t.MyEvent += new EventHandler(t_MyEvent);
    t.FireEvent();
    t.ClearEvent();
    t.FireEvent();
  }
  static void t_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("t_MyEvent");
  }
}`

Comment: It's a bit silly to execute code that doesn't do anything.  But that doesn't matter here, you'll never notice the difference for a Click event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the code you've given here:

```
public virtual void OnMyButtonClick(EventHandler e)
{ 
    if (MyButtonClick!=null)
       this.MyButtonClick(this, e);
}
```

isn't thread-safe. If the final subscription is removed *after* the nullity check but *before* the invocation, you could end up with a `NullReferenceException` (depending on whether the "raising" thread sees the change).

So you can change it to this instead:

```
public virtual void OnMyButtonClick(EventArgs e)
{ 
    var handler = MyButtonClick;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

... but of course you might forget to do that, and even if you don't, it's cumbersome to do that all over the place, IMO. So yes, while the benefit is "only" to avoid the nullity check, I'd say that's not a bad trade-off in many cases. Anything that makes it harder to make mistakes is a good idea, IMO.

Another alternative is to have an extension method:

```
public static void SafeInvoke(this EventHandler handler, object sender,
                              EventArgs e)
{
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(sender, e);
    }       
}
```

Then change your calling code to:

```
public virtual void OnMyButtonClick(EventArgs e)
{
    MyButtonClick.SafeInvoke(this, e);
}
```

(and use the same code for other events). You'd probably want a generic form for `EventHandler<T>` as well.

Comment: The author of C# in Depth! Waaaaaayyy! I asked this question because of your article in the book.

Comment: Well, that solved a weird threading problem I've had for three years. :/

Comment: I'm confused by this answer - is assigning an event to an empty delegate (and subsequently _not_ doing a copy/check/invoke) an accepted practice or is it not thread safe?

Comment: @ScottSEA: It's safe, but not very widely used. What's not thread-safe is the check/invoke that the OP included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do that. If the client that uses you class won't add an handler (subscriber) for `MyButtonClick` event the code won't throw an exception.

That is how events works (and delegates as there are the same thing) otherwise you would be forced to add an handler to all the events of a class (assuming there are any)

so you can do the below:

```
public virtual void OnMyButtonClick(EventArgs e)
{ 
   MyButtonClick(this, e);
}
```

have a look at the example below:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public event EventHandler MyButtonClick = delegate { };

    public void ButtonClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        MyButtonClick(this,e);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testClass=new TestClass();
        testClass.ButtonClick(new EventArgs());

        // if you add an handler it will call it

        testClass.MyButtonClick += myCustomHandler;
        testClass.ButtonClick(new EventArgs()); // myCustomHandler has been invoiked

    }

    private static void myCustomHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("myCustomHandler has been invoiked");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't throw an error if there is no event handler.

Comment: you can do a test to better understand but it won't

Comment: The author of C# in depth wouldn't agree with you.

Comment: your update is wrong.testClass.OnButtonClick it must be a delegate and you should treat it as a field.

from MSDN:Once a class has declared an event, it can treat that event just like a field of the indicated delegate type